# jQuery AJAX Upload to ASMX WebMethod with return values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asmx, webmethod

I'm struggling to get this working. If I include dataType: "json" I always get thrown to request.fail but no errors actually show in the browser console. If I remove dataType: "json" I cannot get the return response: get error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Guid' of undefined.

Everything else works perfectly - file gets uploaded and written to database just fine.

JQuery:

```
$( document ).on( "change", "input[name='files']", function( e ) {

    var files = $( this ).prop( "files");
    var data = new FormData();

    var request;
    var result;
    var modal = $( this ).closest( ".modal" );
    var itemid = modal.data( "itemid" );

    for( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {

        data.append( "id", itemid );
        data.append( "file", files[i] );

        request = $.ajax( {

            type: "POST",
            url: "/webservices/webservices.asmx/UploadFile",
            data: data,
            // dataType: "json",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false

        } );

        request.done( function( response ) {

            result = response.d;
            console.log( result.Guid );

        } );

        request.fail( function( response ) {

            console.log( response.responseText );

        } );

        request.always( function() {

            data.delete( itemid );
            data.delete( files[i] );

        } );

    }

} );
```

WebMethod (simplified for forum purposes):

```
public class Response
{

    public Guid Guid;
    public bool Toggle;
    public string Date;
    public string Text;
    public string Image;

}

[WebMethod]
public Response UploadFile()
{

    Response Response = new Response();

    Response.Guid = BasePage.NewGuid;
    Response.Text = "Hello, world!";
    Response.Image = "/images/test.png";
    return Response;

}
```

Console (request.done - no dataType):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Text' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (eandf.js:218)
    at j (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-latest.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-latest.min.js:4)
```

Console (request.fail - with dataType: json):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="<stripped out>">
    <Guid>53dc43ef-0fe5-4aaf-9866-06d23e3161d2</Guid>
    <Toggle>false</Toggle>
    <Text>Hello, world!</Text>
    <Image>/images/test.png</Image>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
 request = $.ajax( {

            type: "POST",
            url: "/webservices/webservices.asmx/UploadFile",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false,
            cache:false

        } );

var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

//// Use above variable to get the response data
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
  at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
  at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (eandf.js:215)
  at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-latest.min.js:3)
  at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery-latest.min.js:3)
 (anonymous) @ eandf.js:215
 dispatch @ jquery-latest.min.js:3
 r.handle @ jquery-latest.min.js:3

Comment: No matter what I do, when I use FormData in the request with processData: false the response is always XML. Even if I change the WebMethod to return a simple string and not use Response.

So if I do this, it gets around it:

 request.done( function( response ) {
 
  console.log( "Success" );
  console.log( $( response ).find( "Guid" ).text() );
  console.log( $( response ).find( "Text" ).text() );
  console.log( $( response ).find( "Image" ).text() );
  
 } );

Comment: why dont you modify your web method to return JSON instead of XML?

Comment: You mean with [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]? Tried that already.